# Capistrano Deploy Failure - Connection closed by remote host - Tasks: TOP => rbenv:validate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh, capistrano, rbenv

Capistrano is failing to deploy my Ruby on Rails app. I have not altered any configuration files (Capfile, deploy.rb etc.) since my previous successful deployment.

```
chris-iMac:untrackedlatest Chris$ cap production deploy --trace
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke bundler:map_bins (first_time)
** Execute bundler:map_bins
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_rails_env
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env 
** Invoke rbenv:validate (first_time)
** Execute rbenv:validate
DEBUG [eb8ce4ac] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.5 ] as deploy@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
DEBUG [eb8ce4ac] Command: [ -d /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.5 ]
Text will be echoed in the clear. Please install the HighLine or Termios libraries to suppress echoed text.
deploy@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX's password:XXXX
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX: connection closed by remote host
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:16:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Net::SSH::Disconnect: connection closed by remote host
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/packet_stream.rb:105:in `block in next_packet'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/packet_stream.rb:95:in `loop'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/packet_stream.rb:95:in `next_packet'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:183:in `block in poll_message'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:178:in `loop'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:178:in `poll_message'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:163:in `next_message'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:95:in `block in next_message'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:94:in `loop'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:94:in `next_message'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/password.rb:25:in `authenticate'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:79:in `block in authenticate'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:66:in `each'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:66:in `authenticate'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:211:in `start'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `call'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:50:in `create_new_entry'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:22:in `checkout'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:187:in `with_ssh'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:137:in `block in _execute'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:133:in `tap'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:133:in `_execute'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:62:in `test'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capistrano-rbenv-2.0.3/lib/capistrano/tasks/rbenv.rake:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => rbenv:validate
```

Local ruby version:

```
chris-iMac:untrackedlatest Chris$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
```

Remote ruby version:

```
untracked@untrackedprod:/srv/untracked/current$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux]
```

I have not altered anything with regards to ClientAliveInterval / ServerAliveInterval since previous successful deploy.

I am able to successfully SSH into the server.

Capistrano gems:

```
Using capistrano 3.4.0
Using capistrano-bundler 1.1.4
Using capistrano-passenger 0.0.5
Using capistrano-rails 1.1.3
Using capistrano-rbenv 2.0.3
```

Server is running Ubuntu 14.04

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: you can run `ssh deploy@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` in terminal to ssh to remote server, if doesn't work,  please check your ssh key.

Comment: I'm having possibly the very same problem. At rbenv:validate it suddenly needs a password, even though it already connected successfully to the server with a key a moment before. And it doesn't accept the correct password. Deployments have worked perfectly fine in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. I resolve this problem with two steps:

1. I just add one line to the server file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, the content is my local file `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.
2. Because of I have two same account name on my mac and `VirtualBox VM`, and I uncomment one of them in server file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, everything goes well.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the proper solution, but for me starting deployment from new tab/terminal worked. I think the shell restart was required.